# Cannot use Stats.js on @angular/cli 1.4.4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, three.js, angular-cli

I'm trying to use `@types/stats` on `@angular/cli` according to https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-third-party-lib.
But when I try to `import * as STATS from 'stats.js'` I got an tslint error.

`[ts] Module '"stats.js"' resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct.`

`index.d.ts` of @types/stats.

```
declare class Stats {
    REVISION: number;
    dom: HTMLDivElement;
    /**
     * @param value 0:fps, 1: ms, 2: mb, 3+: custom
     */
    showPanel(value: number): void;
    begin(): void;
    end(): number;
    update(): void;
}

declare module "stats.js" {
    export = Stats;
}
```

`src/Stats.js`(Stats.js itself)

https://github.com/mrdoob/stats.js/blob/master/src/Stats.js

I think the reason why I got error is that `@types/stats` uses `export =` style exporting.

So I should use `import Stats = require('stats.js')` But `@angular/cli` uses `"module": "es2015"` by default.

How can I import it?

Comment: yes `import Stats = require('stats.js');` should as the type def is looking like `declare module "stats.js" { export = Stats; }`

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure u installed everything correctly.

`npm install stats-js
npm install @types/stats-js`

You should be able to import it like this:
`import * as STATS from 'stats';`  Without the '.js'.

Comment: Thanks for your replying ;)
I'm trying to use not *stats-js* package but *stats.js* package. They are difference.

Comment: `npm install @types/stats-js` does not exist. It gives `npm ERR! code E404`.